# Proving that $annM$ is a prime ideal for ireducible $M_R$

Tags: ring-theory, modules

If we let $R$ be a ring with $1$ and $M_R$ to be an irreducible right $R$-module then I want to show that $annM]\{r\in R|Mr=0\}$ is a prime ideal.

So if we take $a,b\in R$ with $aRb\subset annM$ then we need to show that either $a\in annM$ or $b\in annM$.

Now as $1\in R$ we have that $ab\in annM$ so that we have $M(ab)=0$. Now suppose that neither $Ma=0$ or $Mb=0$ then as $M$ is irreducible we must have $Ma=M$ and $Mb=M$ but this then gives $M(ab)=(Ma)b=Mb=m$ a contradiction and so one of $a$ or $b$ is in $annM$ and so $ann M$ is prime.

Is this proof correct?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks fine and dandy to me.

Comment: No, it has a minor problem (see below). Aside from that the rest is looks great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 90% of the way there, but there is a mistake in the reasoning at this part: "since $M$ is irreducible, $Ma$ is either $\{0\}$ or $M$."

The problem is that $Ma$ need not be a submodule of $M$.

However, $MaR$ *is* a submodule of $M$, and the logic should be reworked this way: if $MaR=\{0\}$ then we are done because $a\in aR$ annihilates $M$. On the other hand if $MaR=M$, we have immediately that $(MaR)b=M(aRb)=\{0\}$, so that $b$ annihilates $M$.

---

I sometimes see students taking this path of taking a hypothesis and then immediately turning it into a "more familiar" hypothesis. In this case, $aRb=\{0\}$ was used to draw the (much weaker) conclusion $ab=0$, but there did not seem to be any indication this should be done. In fact the full power of $aRb=\{0\}$ was needed for the proof, so we lost a lot by changing it to merely $ab=0$!

So this brings us to a pretty good piece of advice: if you find that you didn't use the full strength of the hypotheses, you should double check the work. On one hand it might have been necessary, and a mistake was made. On the other hand, it might truly be unnecessary, and the statement of the problem could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

This is to write the proof another way(but very much the same reasoning). For simplicity of notation, let me assume that the ring acts on the module on the *left* instead.

The ring $R/(Ann\ M)$ acts on $M$ with zero kernel, i.e., no nonzero element in $R/(Ann\ M)$ acts on $M$ by the zero endomorphism; i.e., if $a \in R/(Ann\ M)$ and $aM= 0$, we get $a = 0$. What we have to prove is that this quotient ring is an integral domain.

Now suppose $a, b$ to be two nonzero elements in this quotient ring $R/(Ann\ M)$. Since $a \neq 0$, $aM \neq 0$. But, irreducibility of $M$ means that, $aM$ , being a nonzero submodule of $M$, has to be $M$ itself. Now since $b \neq 0$, we again have $b(aM) \neq 0$. So, $ba \neq0$. So this ring is a domain, and therefore the ideal $Ann\ M$ is prime.

Comment: @rschwieb: I have edited. Is it fine now?

Comment: Doh, makes the same mistake as the poster made: $aM$ need not be a submodule of $M$ :) Ideally you'd keep the same side of modules too, but that's just aesthetic, not super important.